# Hibernate can't find org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration even though it is there

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, jar

For some strange reason, Hibernate doesn't want to find the cfg.Configuration class in the jar even though it is part of the .classpath. This is what my util class looks like

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() 
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Eclipse is importing it just fine, but I still get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
at com.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:14)
at com.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
at com.helpers.DatabaseManager.getResults(DatabaseManager.java:68)
at com.web.results.ResultsServlet.doPost(ResultsServlet.java:34)
at com.web.results.ResultsServlet.doGet(ResultsServlet.java:21)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Again, I added all the required jars to the .classpath (I'm looking at them right now), so why isn't it finding it?

Here's the config file in case you want it:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">url-to-my-database</property>
    <property name="connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="connection.password">pppsss</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <!-- <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property> -->

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping resource="src/com/models/mappedBeans/TestTesult.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="src/com/models/results/Results.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```

Thanks in advanced.

EDIT: Added more to the error. I think it might have something to do with the loadClass in WebAppClassLoader.

Comment: You're missing *some* dependency; add the libraries you're deploying to your question. I shouldn't have to add that you need to indicate the Hibernate version as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. I'm not using maven or anything like that.

Comment: Maven? Anyway, I'm not sure how to re-word it. There is a dependency missing during runtime. Enumerate the jar files you are deploying.

Comment: Figured it out. I didn't know that it being a webapp meant that it would look for Jars in two places: the classpath and under the WEB-INF folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try use another dependency! For example:

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>42.2.19</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.28.Final</version>
</dependency>
```